# The method findOne(Long) is undefined for the type PersonRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web

I am trying to build simple blog app with Spring boot.However, now I am facing an issue with "The method findOne(Long) is undefined for the type PersonRepository" when I try to use findOne for my service.java.Below are what I did

I tried to create objects in repository indicating findOne and save.However it didn't help

PersonRepository.java

```
package PersonRepository.javaio.javabrains.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import io.javabrains.Entity.Person;
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person,Long>{

public Person findByEmail(String email);

    /*
     * public Person findOne(Long id);
     * 
     * public Iterable<Person> findAll();
     * 
     * public Person save(Person person);
     */
```

PersonService.java

```
@Service
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public Object findAll(){
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Person findById(Long id){
        return personRepository.findOne(id);
    }
```

I expected eliminating comment blocks would solve the issue.However, when I try to run the app ,it shows an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use `JpaRepository` *(which extends the CRUD Repository)*

Instead of *`findOne()`* you can use *`getOne()`* or *`findById()`* *(Optional)*

*findById()*

> Retrieves an entity by its id.
>
> Parameters:id must not be null.
>
> Returns:the entity with the given id or Optional#empty() if none found
>
> Throws:IllegalArgumentException - if id is null.

*getOne()*

> Returns a reference to the entity with the given identifier. Depending
>   on how the JPA persistence provider is implemented this is very likely
>   to always return an instance and throw an
>   javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException on first access. Some of
>   them will reject invalid identifiersimmediately.
>
> Parameters:id must not be null.
>
> Returns:a reference to the entity with the given identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of Spring you are using. It could be that your `findOne`was replaced by `findById`.

So, you repository would become:

```
public Person findByEmail(String email);


     public Person findById(Long id);
```